# Windows UDP Forwarding to multiple ports (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, udp, pcap, portforwarding

I have a very simple problem for understanding, but really hard for me to solve it.

I have 2 applications working with the same UDP packets. I am receiving packets, let's say, on port 25000 and two applications (first is listening on original 25000 port and the second one on port 27000).

What I need to do here is to copy received UDP packet and send it to port 27000 also, but with the same original IP address and port. That keeps us with only modifying only the destination port on the upd packet.

I found a lot **Multi-Port Forwarding** programs, and they indeed forward the UDP packet, but they are not keeping the original one. So when I say, forward 25000 -> 27000, only my second application is receiving.

I tried using **SharpPcap** package and create a simple multiple port forward by myself.

```
private static void device_OnPacketArrival(object sender, CaptureEventArgs e)
        {
            var packet = Packet.ParsePacket(e.Packet.LinkLayerType, e.Packet.Data);
            if (packet is EthernetPacket)
            {
                var device = (ICaptureDevice)sender;                                
                var eth = ((EthernetPacket)packet);                
                var ip = packet.Extract<IPPacket>();
                if (ip != null)
                {
                    var udp = packet.Extract<UdpPacket>();
                    if (udp != null)
                    {
                        udp.DestinationPort = 27000;
                    }                    
                }
                device.SendPacket(eth);
            }
        }
```

If I run this code, in Wireshark I can see that packet was sent again on a different port, but my second application is not receiving it and only the first one on port 25000 is working.

[image: Resending UDP packet]

Is it even possible somehow to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to recalculate the checksum(s) after changing the port number

```
ip.UpdateIpChecksum();
udp.UpdateUdpChecksum();
```